How to handle the image layout transitions between two render passes after the swapchain recreation?
I’m struggling to mount ImGui to my project. So I’ve created two render passes for main render and UI(ImGui) render. Also, as in ImGui recommendation, I made distinct command buffers and frame buffers.
When recreation happens the main command buffers, framebuffers, images, imageView are recreated and the UI’s command buffers and frame buffers are recreated accordingly. The UI recreation happens after the main recreation. Afterwards the error sometimes appear:
VulkanCore: [VULKAN ERROR]: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout ] Object 0: handle = 0x2aab4061990, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x4dae5635 | vkQueueSubmit(): pSubmits[0].pCommandBuffers[1] command buffer VkCommandBuffer 0x2aab4061990[] expects VkImage 0xd0e29300000000aa[] (subresource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0) to be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL--instead, current layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED.
VulkanCore: [VULKAN ERROR]: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296 ] Object 0: handle = 0x2aab3d21540, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; | MessageID = 0xc7aabc16 | vkQueuePresentKHR(): pSwapchains[0] images passed to present must be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR but is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pImageIndices must be the index of a presentable image acquired from the swapchain specified by the corresponding element of the pSwapchains array, and the presented image subresource must be in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR layout at the time the operation is executed on a VkDevice (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/search?q=)VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296)

I’ve heard of image memory barriers, but I don’t comperhend how to implement them and I think that it is possible to avoid them. I don't undersand how to transition image firstly to color optimal then to present.
So there is the code of creation of two render passes:
//the main one
// Color attachment setup
const vk::AttachmentDescription colorAttachment(
    vk::AttachmentDescriptionFlags(),           // Flags (default)
    swapchainImageFormat,                       // Format of the swapchain images
    vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1,                // Sample count (1 sample per pixel)
    vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eClear,               // Clear attachment at the start of the render pass
    vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eStore,              // Store the attachment after the render pass finishes
    vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare,            // Stencil load operation (not used here)
    vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare,           // Stencil store operation (not used here)
    vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined,                // Initial layout before rendering
    vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal    // Final layout for color attachment after rendering
);

// Depth attachment setup
const vk::AttachmentDescription depthAttachment(
    vk::AttachmentDescriptionFlags(),           // Flags (default)
    DeviceManager::FindSupportedFormat(physicalDevice,  // Find a suitable depth format
        {vk::Format::eD32Sfloat, vk::Format::eD32SfloatS8Uint, vk::Format::eD24UnormS8Uint}, 
        vk::ImageTiling::eOptimal, vk::FormatFeatureFlagBits::eDepthStencilAttachment),
    vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1,                // 1 sample per pixel
    vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eClear,               // Clear depth attachment at the start
    vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare,           // Don't store depth data after rendering
    vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare,            // No stencil load operation
    vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare,           // No stencil store operation
    vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined,                // Initial layout (undefined)
    vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal // Optimal layout for depth/stencil attachment
);

// Attachment references for the subpass
const vk::AttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef(0, vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal); // Refers to the color attachment
const vk::AttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef(1, vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal); // Refers to the depth attachment

// Subpass description
const vk::SubpassDescription subpassDescription(
    vk::SubpassDescriptionFlags(),              // Flags (none)
    vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics,           // Subpass used in graphics pipeline
    0,                                          // Input attachments (none)
    nullptr,                                    // Pointer to input attachments (none)
    1,                                          // Color attachment count
    &colorAttachmentRef,                        // Reference to color attachment
    nullptr,                                    // Resolve attachments (none)
    &depthAttachmentRef                         // Reference to depth attachment
);

// Subpass dependency (for handling pipeline transitions)
const vk::SubpassDependency subpassDependency(
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,                        // Source subpass (external dependency)
    0,                                          // Destination subpass
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput | vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eEarlyFragmentTests, // Source stage (before rendering)
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput | vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eEarlyFragmentTests, // Destination stage (during rendering)
    vk::AccessFlagBits::eNone,                  // Source access mask (no read/write operations before rendering)
    vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite | vk::AccessFlagBits::eDepthStencilAttachmentWrite // Destination access mask (write operations for color and depth)
);

// Array of attachments (color + depth)
std::array<vk::AttachmentDescription, 2> attachments{ colorAttachment, depthAttachment };

// Render pass creation info
const vk::RenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo(
    vk::RenderPassCreateFlagBits(),             // Flags (default)
    attachments.size(),                         // Number of attachments
    attachments.data(),                         // Pointer to the attachments
    1,                                          // Number of subpasses
    &subpassDescription,                        // Subpass description
    1,                                          // Number of dependencies
    &subpassDependency                          // Subpass dependency description
);

// Create the render pass and return it
return device.createRenderPass(renderPassInfo);

//the UI’s
// Define the color attachment description
const vk::AttachmentDescription colorAttachment(
    vk::AttachmentDescriptionFlags(),              // Flags
    swapchainImageFormat,                          // Format of the swapchain image
    vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1,                   // Sample count (no multisampling)
    vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eLoad,                   // Load operation (load existing data)
    vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eStore,                 // Store operation (store after rendering)
    vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare,               // Stencil load operation (don't care)
    vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare,              // Stencil store operation (don't care)
    vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal,      // Initial layout (optimal for color attachments)
    vk::ImageLayout::ePresentSrcKHR                // Final layout (ready for presentation)
);

// Reference to the color attachment
const vk::AttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef(
    0,                                             // Attachment index in the render pass
    vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal       // Layout used in the subpass
);

// Describe the subpass
const vk::SubpassDescription subpassDescription(
    vk::SubpassDescriptionFlags(),                 // Subpass flags
    vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics,              // Pipeline bind point (graphics)
    0,                                             // No input attachments
    nullptr,                                       // No input attachments array
    1,                                             // One color attachment
    &colorAttachmentRef,                           // Reference to the color attachment
    nullptr,                                       // No resolve attachments
    nullptr                                        // No depth/stencil attachment
);

// Define subpass dependency (synchronization)
const vk::SubpassDependency subpassDependency{
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,                           // Source subpass (external)
    0,                                             // Destination subpass (subpass 0)
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput, // Wait at color attachment output
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput, // Signal at color attachment output
    vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite,     // Wait for color attachment write access
    vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite      // Ensure color attachment write access
};

// Define array of attachments
std::array attachments{ colorAttachment };

// Create render pass creation info
const vk::RenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo{
    vk::RenderPassCreateFlags(),                   // Flags for render pass creation
    attachments.size(),                            // Number of attachments
    attachments.data(),                            // Pointer to attachment descriptions
    1,                                             // One subpass
    &subpassDescription,                           // Pointer to subpass description
    1,                                             // One subpass dependency
    &subpassDependency                             // Pointer to subpass dependency
};

// Create and return the render pass
return device.createRenderPass(renderPassInfo);

How should I handle the image layout transitions between these two render passes after the recreation?
Any advice or pointers would be highly appreciated!
Edit:
I put these barriers and it keeps throwing errors. The pseudo code of rendering:
vector commandBuffers{cmdBuff, UICmdBuff};

//undefined -> color optimal
RecordBarrier(cmdBuff, image);
//color optimal -> present
RecordBarrier(UICmdBuff, image, ...);

renderer.BeginSwapchainRenderPass(cmdBuff);
UI.BeginRenderPass(UICmdBuff);

UI.RenderFrame(UICmdBuff);

UI.EndRenderPass(UICmdBuff);
renderer.EndSwapchainRenderPass(cmdBuff);

bool recreate = renderer.EndFrame(commandBuffers);

if(recreate)
{
    ImGui_ImplVulkan_SetMinImageCount(...);
    UI.Recreate(...);
}


To handle image layout transitions between your main render pass and the ImGui render pass in Vulkan, you need to use image memory barriers. Before each render pass, record a barrier to transition the image from its current layout (e.g., VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL) to the required layout (e.g., VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL for rendering and VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR for presentation).
Add this barrier before your render pass commands:
vk::ImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
barrier.image = swapchainImage;
barrier.oldLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined; // Adjust as needed
barrier.newLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal; // Adjust as needed
barrier.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eNone; 
barrier.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;
commandBuffer.pipelineBarrier(vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eTopOfPipe, vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput, {}, barrier.srcAccessMask, barrier.dstAccessMask, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

Update
Please try this:
vk::ImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
barrier.image = swapchainImage;
barrier.oldLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined;
barrier.newLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal;
barrier.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eNone;
barrier.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;
barrier.subresourceRange = { vk::ImageAspectFlagBits::eColor, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

commandBuffer.pipelineBarrier(
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eTopOfPipe,
    vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput,
    {},
    barrier.srcAccessMask,
    barrier.dstAccessMask,
    {},
    {},
    { barrier }
);



So should I use a barrier for an ImGui's command buffer and the main one, before the render passes begin accordingly?

Moreover your code does not compile: "'vk::CommandBuffer::pipelineBarrier': no matching overloaded function found".

@shampoo, Yes, use a barrier for both the main command buffer and ImGui's command buffer before the render passes.
